# SQL developer - duplicate entry of unique ID in join result

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Table **Provider**

```
ID  NAME
1   name1
2   name2
3   name3
```

Table **Lang**

```
ID  Lan
1   English
2   English
2   Tamil
3   English
3   Tamil
3   Telugu
```

the join result was

```
1   name1   English
2   name2   English
2   name2   Tamil
3   name3   English
3   name3   Tamil
3   name3   Telugu
```

But I need the result like

```
id  Name   Lan1    Lan2  Lan3
1   name1  English NULL  NULL
2   name2  English Tamil NULL
3   name3  English Tamil TELUGU
```

can you please help

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: pivoting is the only answer.if number of language is dynamic then dynamic pivot sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this pivot query, which *should* work on both MySQL and SQL Server (you never told us which one you are really using).  The `MAX()` function should ignore `null` values for both of these RDBMS.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.NAME, MAX(t.Lan1) AS Lan1, MAX(t.Lan2) AS Lan2, MAX(t.Lan3) AS Lan3
FROM
(
    SELECT p.ID, p.NAME,
        CASE WHEN l.Lan = 'English' THEN 'English' ELSE null END AS Lan1,
        CASE WHEN l.Lan = 'Tamil'   THEN 'Tamil'   ELSE null END AS Lan2
        CASE WHEN l.Lan = 'Telugu'  THEN 'Telugu'  ELSE null END AS Lan3
    FROM Provider p INNER JOIN Lang l ON p.ID = l.ID
) t
GROUP BY t.ID, t.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

on mysql

```
select ID,NAME
,(select LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='English' limit 1)  
as LAN1 
,(select LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='Tamil' limit 1)  
as LAN2 
,(select LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='Telugu' limit 1)  
as LAN3 
from PROVIDER;
```

on sqlserver thanks to @Bungicasse for answer

```
select ID,NAME
,(select TOP 1 LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='English')  
as LAN1 
,(select TOP 1 LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='Tamil' )  
as LAN2 
,(select TOP 1 LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='Telugu')  
as LAN3 
from PROVIDER;
```

and the build schema script
on mysql

```
drop table if exists  LANG;
drop table if exists  PROVIDER;
CREATE TABLE LANG (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  LAN varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (1, 'English');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (2, 'English');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (2, 'Tamil');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (3, 'English');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (3, 'Tamil');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (3, 'Telugu');

CREATE TABLE PROVIDER (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
);

INSERT INTO PROVIDER VALUES (1, 'name1');
INSERT INTO PROVIDER VALUES (2, 'name2');
INSERT INTO PROVIDER VALUES (3, 'name3');
```

on mssql

```
CREATE TABLE LANG (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  LAN varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (1, 'English');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (2, 'English');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (2, 'Tamil');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (3, 'English');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (3, 'Tamil');
INSERT INTO lang (ID, Lan) VALUES (3, 'Telugu');

CREATE TABLE PROVIDER (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
);

INSERT INTO PROVIDER VALUES (1, 'name1');
INSERT INTO PROVIDER VALUES (2, 'name2');
INSERT INTO PROVIDER VALUES (3, 'name3');
```

test it here

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL-Server you should change @Alice code because LIMIT 1 wont work, instead use TOP 1.

```
select ID,NAME 
,(select TOP 1 LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='English')  
as LAN1 
,(select TOP 1 LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='Tamil')  
as LAN2 
,(select TOP 1 LAN from LANG where LANG.id=PROVIDER.ID and LAN='Telugu')  
as LAN3 
from PROVIDER;
```